# twitter gem not loaded after bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, twitter-gem

I am new to rails and I am trying to make an app using twitter gem.

This is my gemfile:
`gem "twitter", "~> 4.6.2"
gem "faraday", "~> 0.8"
gem "multi_json", "~> 1"
gem "simple_oauth", "~> 0.2.0"`

and I ve made bundle install, but I still get error when trying to start it,
cannot load such file -- twitter
app/controllers/start_controller.rb:2:in `'
This error occurred while loading the following files:twitter

The error doesn't help me to find whats missing. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: can you share a code snippet where you're using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try restarting the server. It is a must after installing a gem.

Comment: Thank you really much! I just needed to restart the server for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Check your gemfile properly. There may be some kind of syntax error.